# What does 'explanatory foil' mean?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context

What does 'explanatory foil' mean?

> Ortony's construct of linguistic metaphor (1975) as an **explanatory
>   foil**.

Article: 'Meaning and visual metaphor' by Hermine Feinstein

Comment: I think that adding more context as well as attaching the source you got this quote from can help you significantly reduce the time you must wait for the answer.

Comment: Maybe just adding source: https://www.jstor.org/stable/1319679?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: I read this article. It is interesting what is 'FOIL' here for native speaker.

Comment: @Vitaly When Michael asked for more context, he means context of the sentence (i.e. what is relevant to the meaning of the words) and not context of your question (i.e. that you were reading an article). While context about your question can be helpful, context about the sentence is much more helpful.

Comment: You need to read Ortony's work. There are many interpretations of what metaphors actually are.

Comment: I can not find Ortony's work in public access. Could you give me the link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this context, **a foil is "someone or something that serves as a contrast to another"**. See the third noun definition under the second entry in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/foil) and the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foil_(literature)).

The article will discuss Langer's thesis by drawing comparisons with Ortony's construct of linguistic metaphor (whatever that is). The differences between the two will facilitate the discussion.

For simplicity, let's call Langer's thesis "Thing One" and Ortony's construct of linguistic metaphor "Thing Two".

In other words, Thing One is different from Thing Two, and discussing these differences can help us understand Thing One. When we do this, we are using Thing Two as a foil to Thing One. Since we are using this foil to *explain* Thing One, we can call Thing Two an ***explanatory foil***.

Comment: I don't understand fully. Probably it has to read another article A.Ortony 'Metaphor and Thought' to understand what it means.

Comment: @Vitaly "Foil" has a standard definition that does not depend on any of the articles in this specific case.

Comment: @Vitaly I hope my edits will help clarify.

Comment: I see. So it can be replaced by "explanatory contrast"?

Comment: @vitaly similar. A foil has a more deliberate connotation. See the added Wikipedia link.

Comment: I have not found a term which replace 'foil (in literature)' in Russian laguage. The closest term is 'Antagonist' in Russian. The difference is foil highlights attributes in other characters, foils are not always antagonist. Source is here:  https://writingexplained.org/grammar-dictionary/foil